# How to know deep inside component hierarchy we have a special component, efficiently?

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm creating a form builder using React.

The point is, everything is dynamic.

A form can have fields, or field groups. Each field group can have many fields. Each field can have it's own controls, hints, valdiations, etc.

This means that a form is a component hierarchy. A tree of components.

Now I want to know if in this tree, any `Upload` field exist at all.

Because if there is no `Upload` field, then I submit the form using `application/json` content type. Otherwise I would submit the form using `application/form-data` content type.

I know I can traverse the entire JSON of component props. But that seems very inefficient.

Is there a way to traverse React's component tree in an efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by using contextApi or with its hook for React Version > 16.8 the useContext. 
Read more in [React official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html#how-to-use-context)

My suggestion is to use formik npm package to build your form correctly and easily, formik using context for managing the state behind the scene.
 I recommend it for regular use of forms, not heavy form with many fields (~25-30 max) like in enterprises.

You can read about formik more here:
https://formik.org/docs/api/formik

There is another alternative for formik which is also popular in react using forms: 
react form hook: https://react-hook-form.com/

 I didn't use it yet but as I know it has some pros/cons over formik.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is vanilla JS.

```
const FORM_SELECTOR = '#some-form-id';
const UPLOAD_SELECTOR = '.some-upload-class';

const form = document.querySelector(FORM_SELECTOR)
if(form.querySelectorAll(UPLOAD_SELECTOR).length) {
  // upload exists
} else {
  // upload does not exist
}
```